# Eclipse JUNO - edit .class

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have got .jar imported to my project. There are some files .class but I am not able to change this files. I have to add I have got Juno Eclipse and I am using Java1.6 Is it possible to edit .class using eclipse or another software?

I gave you points thanks for help, good support. [closed]

Comment: `.class` files are compiled. You can only edit `.java` files. Find the source code for the jar -- *not* the class files -- and then edit that and rebuild the jar.

Comment: Why don't you extend the classes you would like to modify?

Comment: @Adam Arold  I would be honest I searching some ways to fix this issue. I believe this topic is very important because before I searching in Google and I didn`t find good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you need is to import/edit files in your project, not `.class` files. `.class` files are machine-readable files that are interpreted by the JVM. 
But if you knew already that, and you are wondering how can you see the code that produced a `.class` file you can use a java decompiler like [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/). From Eclipse you can use [this](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse) plugin to automatically decompile the class for you.

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper you can use the plugin that I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly edit .class files.  Those files are the result of compiling java classes. You must get the original class file, modify it and then compile it.  There are ways to do it directly, such as [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) but that's normally only done at runtime out of necessity in very special cases and it's not common practice.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly edit a .class file as it is compiled.  You need the .java files to go with it.  You could use a java decompiler on the classes, generate the source, and then recompile them.

[JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui)  - I have used this previously.  There is a plugin, but I feel like the standalone app tends to work better.

Comment: Ok. but how change .class to .java

Comment: @Rafael - Edited.  If this is a third party jar you should be careful about attempting to modify it as this could lead to a lot of headaches down the road.

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper See my answer for a solution from Eclipse.